# Creating a "Live" ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

From either a high-level perspective, or a low level and very specific one, what is the best way to constantly poll a database for updates?

I would like to create a "live" application which, using ajax, displays the most current data.  I have partial views which Ajax.ActionLink the correct data in, but only OnClick of that generated link.

Is using a trigger and some sort of application code the best way to do this? For example, a trigger on all tables, which sets some field as "changes have been made since last read"?

Or is it better to use a function to poll the database on an interval to check for changes (I for-see this possibly being taxing with all the constant chatter to the DB)?

Or is a combination of these 2 approaches best?  Or is there something I am leaving out completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) was designed to solve exactly this problem.